# Which instructions can not be issued in specific CPU ring

Tags: x86, cpu

According to [this source](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev12.html) (Level 3 - 5) specific CPU rings can not do certain things, such as ring 1, 2, 3 code can not set up GDT, as os kernel would crash.

While it is obvious that Ring 0 can execute all instructions, **I am wondering which instructions can not be issued in rings 1, 2 and 3?**

I could not find anything on either wikipedia or osdev and similar sources which would state what instructions can not be issued in specific ring.

Comment: Anything that has "#GP(0)  If the current privilege level is not 0." listed in the PMode exceptions

Comment: Have you read sections 5.5 to 5.9 in the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual?

Comment: @Michael no but I will take a look at it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following instructions cannot be executed in Ring 3:

```
LGDT
LLDT
LTR
LIDT
MOV (to and from control registers only)
MOV (to and from debug registers only)
LMSW
CLTS
INVD
WBINVD
INVLPG
HLT
RDMSR
WRMSR
RDPMC
RDTSC
```